# angular router destroy route's stored component on demand

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an angular app where I am implementing a Route Reuse Strategy class which checks for a value stored on my route object in the `shouldDetach()` method. Like this:

```
  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        if (route.data.shouldReuse == true) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

For the most part I want the component that is returned by the route to be cached when a user browses away... in other words I want any user customization of the state to persist and I want rxjs subscriptions to persist. But sometimes, on certain user input I want to be able to reset the route and allow for onDestroy to be fired on the route's component.

The only way I have found thus far to do this is to:

1. Programmatically change my route's `shouldReuse` value to `false` in the route config object.
2. Navigate to some other route using `this.router.navigate()`.
3. Navigate to the route that I want to destroy.
4. Then navigate to some other route.

Only then does `ngOnDestroy()` fire on the route I am trying to destroy... allowing me to unsubscribe from observables.

This is obviously a very hacky means of destroying my route's saved component. I need some other method of doing this in response to user action.

Is it possible to access a `.destroy` method on a route directly? What about other methods in my Route Reuse Strategy class, can I leverage any of them to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same use case as you. Did you have any luck solving this?